# Setting source again refreshes iFrame?

Tags: javascript, caching, iframe

I am using the below to set my iFrames content, but will setting the same url a second time refresh the content in all browsers? Or do I need to use http://targeturl.com/targetpage?random=*currenttime* to prevent caching and cause a reload?

```
function setIframeSource(Iframe, targetUrl){
var Elem = document.getElementById(Iframe);
Elem.src = targetUrl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it will definitely reload the page, but caching might be handled differently depending on the browser/version/server and even user settings, so if you want to refresh it properly - use cachebuster (time).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to force a cache refresh like this on web pages, unless you know that that particular web page needs a forced cache refresh.

If you needed to append a cache refresh querystring to every web page in an `iframe`, then this would be true for accessing any web page in your browser, which obviously isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it shouldn't refresh the iFrame if the URL is the same or only the fragment identifier (# part) changes, but you might need to test this on a few browsers (particularly IE which never seems to follow specs)

If you are setting the URL with Javascript, why don't you call the reload() method of the iframe? Eseentially, that iframe is a window, and contains the same methods you would have for a normal window object.